# How to import ABI types from ethers.js typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity, ethers.js

How can I import ABI types for typescript?

```
    import {ABI} from "ethers"

    const myFunction = (abi: ABI) =>{
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember that web3-utils had this built in, so I just grabbed the types from the there package:

Simple create your own file with this code and import AbiItem.

```
export type AbiType = 'function' | 'constructor' | 'event' | 'fallback';
export type StateMutabilityType = 'pure' | 'view' | 'nonpayable' | 'payable';

export interface AbiItem {
  anonymous?: boolean;
  constant?: boolean;
  inputs?: AbiInput[];
  name?: string;
  outputs?: AbiOutput[];
  payable?: boolean;
  stateMutability?: StateMutabilityType;
  type: AbiType;
  gas?: number;
}

export interface AbiInput {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  indexed?: boolean;
  components?: AbiInput[];
  internalType?: string;
}

export interface AbiOutput {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  components?: AbiOutput[];
  internalType?: string;
}
```

rock on